# https and third party contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, https

When I insert some content from 3rd party websites on my website footer (for example a YouTube movie or a Flickr image preview or a Google map) I have a problem on https pages: all the browsers raise a warning saying `Only secure content is displayed`. How can I avoid it without removing https (some website areas require it)?

The website is based on ASP.NET MVC 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the link is available both as http and https and you want to embbed it in page that is both http and https, you can do this :

```
<img src="//url.tld/path/to/file.png" alt="" />
```

(notice that http nor https is present : the browser will select the proper one)

Comment: I does not work for me sorry... I removed `http://` form this `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` and nothing shows up...

Comment: Much better thanks, on IE10 I always get the warning but at least the content is there.